# Plotly-Dash How to Use dcc.Input to pass input as JSON Serialized variable?

Tags: json, python-3.x, plotly-dash

Hi everyone I am trying to build an interface for my scraper application and I am having a difficult time with passing user input into a variable I have tried everything and keep getting an error that my inputs are **Object of type function is not JSON serializable**. I am also getting this callback error:

> raise exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue(
> dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `<Output` output-submit.children`>`
> returned a value having type `tuple`
> which is not JSON serializable.
> The value in question is either the only value returned,
> or is in the top level of the returned list,
> and has string representation
> `(<function CSV at 0x11e00a430>, <function pages at 0x104cf4160>, <function url at 0x11e004550>)`
> In general, Dash properties can only be
> dash components, strings, dictionaries, numbers, None,
> or lists of those.

here is my code if you would like to help! I appreciate any help I can get.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        html.Header(
            html.H1("Price Scraper")
        )
    ),
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label(' address:'),
        dcc.Input(
            id='input-url',
            placeholder='Input Address',
            type="text",
            style={"width": "25%"}
        ),
        html.Div(id='output-url'),
        # ____________________________#
        html.Label('How many pages to scrape:'),
        dcc.Input(
            id='input-pages',
            placeholder='Input or choose pages to scrape',
            type="number",
            min="0"
        ),
        html.Div(id='output-pages'),
        # -----------------------------#
        html.Label('CSV Filename:'),
        dcc.Input(
            id='input-csv',
            placeholder='Input filename ending in .csv',
            type="text"
        ),
        html.Div(id='output-csv'),
        # ------------------------------#
        html.Button('submit',
                    id='input-submit'),
        html.Div(id='output-submit',
                 children='Click the button to run program'),
    ]),
])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-url', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input-url', component_property='value')]
)
def url(input_value):
    url = str(input_value)



# ---------------#
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-pages', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input-pages', component_property='value')]
)
def pages(input_value):
    pages = str(input_value)



# ---------------#
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-csv', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input-csv', component_property='value')]
)
def CSV(input_value):
    CSV = str(input_value)





#---------------#
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-submit', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input-submit', component_property='n_clicks')]
)

def run_script(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        print(CSV, pages, url)
# ---------------#
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You are trying to print CSV, pages, url, which are functions. I guess that is not intended?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

1. Your callbacks aren't `return`ing any values. They need to do that in order to work properly.
2. Your last callback is trying to use values that are out of scope (`CSV`, `pages, and` url`). Think of each callback func as completely independent of the others, because they cannot reach into different ones and use those values. In order to use a value in a callback func, you need to pass it in as an` Input`or`State`, or use a global variable (not recommended).

Here is how I would change these funcs (I haven't tried running this, but I think you'll get the idea).

```py
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-url', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input-url', component_property='value')]
)
def url(input_value):
    return str(input_value)


# ---------------#
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-pages', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input-pages', component_property='value')]
)
def pages(input_value):
    return str(input_value)


# ---------------#
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-csv', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input-csv', component_property='value')]
)
def CSV(input_value):
    return str(input_value)


#---------------#
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-submit', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input-submit', component_property='n_clicks')],
    [State(component_id='output-url', component_property='children'),
     State(component_id='output-pages', component_property='children'),
     State(component_id='output-csv', component_property='children'),
    ]
)

def run_script(n_clicks, url, pages, CSV):
    if n_clicks:
        return [CSV, pages, url]
    else:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
```

You could probably even skip the first 3 callback funcs and hook everything up to the 4th one, but I hope this shows how to relate the various callbacks together.

Comment: Worked Perfectly!

Comment: Hi This code no longer works :/ and is returning a none-type value? Can I messge you privately?

Comment: Stackoverflow unfortunately doesnt have a messaging system, so I sent you an email! Please respond whenever you can I really appreciate it!